# Active Directory Admin group

Tags: c#, .net

I want to check if user is system admin in Active Directory.

I am using the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, "Administrators");

    var existsInGroup = group
      .GetMembers(true)
      .Where(p => p.UserPrincipalName == txtUser.Text)
      .Any();

    MessageBox.Show(existsInGroup.ToString());
}
```

For e certain reason, it always returns false.

I've tried changing the group to sadmin and other groups I managed to identify, but I'm getting the same result for user accounts that I know are administrators.

Any ideas where I could be missing something?

Comment: Code seems to be working, so the most probable reason is that text is never the same as any `UserPrincipalName`. Check if you type the name right (they are prefixed by domain name in my case). Also, you don't need `Where` here, just move lambda from it to `Any`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this :

```
    bool checkUserGroup()
    {
        List<GroupPrincipal> userGroups = new List<GroupPrincipal>();

        PrincipalContext currentDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        UserPrincipal usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(currentDomain, "yourUserName");

        if (usr != null)
        {
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> foundGroups = usr.GetAuthorizationGroups();

            foreach (Principal p in foundGroups)
            {
                if (p is GroupPrincipal)
                {
                    userGroups.Add((GroupPrincipal)p);
                }
            }
        }

        return userGroups.Any(ro => ro.Name == "Administrators"); //Administrtor keyword can vary depending on the cultur.
    }
```